# local webpage could not display correctly when it is in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, orientation

I have an index html using WKWebView and I load it using subview into the mainview. It is in Swift. It display fine when it is in portraight. It display incorrectly when it is in landscape. Is there a way that I need to tell the subview that it needs to be resize. I also add some code for rotation but it did not work.

```
    //This lock of code is in viewDidLoad
    theWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667))
    theWebView!.loadHTMLString(content!, baseURL: url)
    self.view.addSubview(theWebView!)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "checkOrientation", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

func checkOrientation()
{
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        println("landscape")
        theWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 667, height: 375))
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        println("portraight")
        theWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 25, width: 375, height: 667))
    }

}
```

Comment: Add some rotation detection code to resize the web view on rotation.